TemplateDoesNotExist by inheriting LoginView
django cannot find my template but I give it correct path
I make customize view for login by inheriting LoginView and form_class of AuthenticationForm from django. I give correct template_name to view but django cannot find it. I used mixin views for register and give template like this and I did'nt give error, so I check definition of LoginView and modify it's template_name to that I writed on my view class and it run without error
this is my view class:
class LoginAuthView(LoginView):
    
    form_class = AuthenticationForm
    template_name = 'login.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('accounts:test')
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if 'form' not in kwargs:
            kwargs['form'] = self.get_form()
        return kwargs

    def form_valid(self, form: AuthenticationForm) -> HttpResponse:
        response = super().form_valid(form)
        messages.success(self.request, f'Welcome {self.request.user}!')
        return response


The default location of html template files is <your project>/<your app>/templates/<your app>/login.html
E.g. Project Name : college App Name : blog then your template should be available in college/blog/templates/blog/login.html

thanks for your answer, I did that but nothing happened. you know django doesn't access to me to customize template_name and set it my path

Share the error message along with settings.py file

Could You give us your settings, and info where is your template.
If you are using it in the base project folder.
The settings.py should look like this:
'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
If you are using few templates folder lets say 1 in base project folder and second in your app folder , you have to specify the path:
template_name = '<appname>/login.html'

thanks for your answer but yeah I have many templates that I use in my app and also project. so I did your first solution before make app and ... . now it's give me this error so I look LoginView definition and make path that template_name define on it, so django run it without error
